# how can I sort MLE Probability according to the value?

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
bigrams = tuple(nltk.bigrams(tokens))
bi_freq = nltk.FreqDist(bigrams)
bigram_count = 0
for k,v in sorted(bi_freq.items(), key = lambda (k, v) : (v, k), reverse = True):
    number_unigrams = tokens.count(k[0])
    MLE_Prob = v / number_unigrams
    bigram_count += v
    print k, MLE_Prob
```

But the result is not according to the value of `MLE_Prob`. It means, sorting by '`v`' value is in vain ( maybe it's a matter of course).
What I want is, `MLE_Prob` should be arranged according to frequency and its matching '`k`' value (i.e. `bigram`).

```
("red", "apple") 0.083222
("brown", "apple") 0.073222
```

such like this. I don't know how to apply sorting function for this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often it's helpful to put data in the right format (get the columns you want) as one step, then print it out as a separate step, rather than to try and combine everything into one loop.

```
from __future__ import print_function

bigrams = tuple(nltk.bigrams(tokens))
bi_freq = nltk.FreqDist(bigrams)

# Calculate data here
mle_probs = {k: v / tokens.count(k[0])
             for k, v in bi_freq.iteritems()}
bigram_count = sum(bi_freq.itervalues())

# Then display it, sorted
for k, v in sorted(mle_probl, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: I got a attribute error, tuple object has no attribute 'iteritems' :(, but appriciate your advice.

Comment: @YounginNa: That's why you shouldn't copy code... it might have errors in it.  I've fixed the errors, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sort on `v` and not on `(v, k)`

```
sorted(bi_freq.items(), key = lambda (k, v) : v, reverse = True)
```

Comment: sort on v doesn't result what I want. MLE_prob = v / number_unigrams. so sorting on v or k or (k,v) or (v, k) doesn't look appropriate for what I want. I want to sort the Probability itself.